# orthogonal projection formula question

Tags: linear-algebra

V=R^3 is an Inner product space  and U=span {(1,2,1),(1,2,3)} is a subspace.
I need to find an explicit formula for the orthogonal projection for  Pu.
I found an orthonormal base for U but I stucked with finding a formula for the projection.

Comment: If $(e_1,e_2)$ is an orthonormal basis for $U$, then the projection of $v\in V$ onto $U$ is given by $$\langle e_1,v\rangle e_1 + \langle e_2,v\rangle e_2.$$

Comment: Why are you saying that $(1,2,3)\in \Bbb R^4$?

Comment: @rschwieb you right;, i changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the orthogonal projection onto that plane, the strategy is simple:

1. Find the unit normal $n$ to the plane. (Hint: cross product)
2. Use the transformation that "removes" the component of a vector $v$ which is parallel to $n$ ($(v\cdot n)n$ is the part of $v$ parallel to $n$):

$$p(v)=v-(v\cdot n)n$$

Try your hand at these two steps.